How to make Mathematica simplify `1 - Cos[x]^2` as `Sin[x]^2`?
By running this code
v = 1/2 (1 - Sum[(2 l + 1)/l * LegendreP[l + 1, 0] * LegendreP[l, Cos[θ]] * r^l, {l, 1, Infinity}]);
e = -Grad[v, {r, θ, φ}, "Spherical"];
d = FullSimplify[Div[e, {r, θ, φ}, "Spherical"]];
Print[d];

I get
(2*r*Sum[(1 + 2*l)*r^(-1 + l)*LegendreP[l, Cos[\[Theta]]]*LegendreP[1 + l, 0], {l, 1, Infinity}] + r^2*Sum[(1 + 2*l)*(-r^(-2 + l) + l*r^(-2 + l))*LegendreP[l, Cos[\[Theta]]]*LegendreP[1 + l, 0], {l, 1, Infinity}] + Cot[\[Theta]]*Sum[-(((1 + 2*l)*r^l*LegendreP[1 + l, 0]*((-1 - l)*Cos[\[Theta]]*LegendreP[l, Cos[\[Theta]]] + (1 + l)*LegendreP[1 + l, Cos[\[Theta]]])*Sin[\[Theta]])/(l*(-1 + Cos[\[Theta]]^2))), {l, 1, Infinity}] + Sum[-(((1 + 2*l)*r^l*Cos[\[Theta]]*LegendreP[1 + l, 0]*((-1 - l)*Cos[\[Theta]]*LegendreP[l, Cos[\[Theta]]] + (1 + l)*LegendreP[1 + l, Cos[\[Theta]]]))/(l*(-1 + Cos[\[Theta]]^2))) - (2*(1 + 2*l)*r^l*Cos[\[Theta]]*LegendreP[1 + l, 0]*((-1 - l)*Cos[\[Theta]]*LegendreP[l, Cos[\[Theta]]] + (1 + l)*LegendreP[1 + l, Cos[\[Theta]]])*Sin[\[Theta]]^2)/(l*(-1 + Cos[\[Theta]]^2)^2) - ((1 + 2*l)*r^l*LegendreP[1 + l, 0]*Sin[\[Theta]]*(-((-1 - l)*LegendreP[l, Cos[\[Theta]]]*Sin[\[Theta]]) - ((-1 - l)*Cos[\[Theta]]*((-1 - l)*Cos[\[Theta]]*LegendreP[l, Cos[\[Theta]]] + (1 + l)*LegendreP[1 + l, Cos[\[Theta]]])*Sin[\[Theta]])/(-1 + Cos[\[Theta]]^2) - ((1 + l)*((-2 - l)*Cos[\[Theta]]*LegendreP[1 + l, Cos[\[Theta]]] + (2 + l)*LegendreP[2 + l, Cos[\[Theta]]])*Sin[\[Theta]])/(-1 + Cos[\[Theta]]^2)))/(l*(-1 + Cos[\[Theta]]^2)), {l, 1, Infinity}])/(2*r^2)

which I think should be 0.
The main problem I think is that 1 - Cos[x]^2 isn't changed into Sin[x]^2. If Mathematica can't do it automatically I'd like to have it done manually. How can I achieve this?

The problem seems to be that the summand is inaccessible to Simplify:
simplifySummand = Sum[s_, i__] :> With[{ss = Simplify[s]}, Sum[ss, i]];

v = 1/2 (1 - 
     Sum[(2 l + 1)/l*LegendreP[l + 1, 0]*LegendreP[l, Cos[\[Theta]]]*
       r^l, {l, 1, Infinity}]);
e = -Grad[v, {r, \[Theta], \[CurlyPhi]}, "Spherical"] /. 
   simplifySummand;
d = Simplify[
  Div[e, {r, \[Theta], \[CurlyPhi]}, "Spherical"] /. simplifySummand]

Alternate method:
v = 1/2 (1 - 
     Sum[(2 l + 1)/l*LegendreP[l + 1, 0]*LegendreP[l, Cos[\[Theta]]]*
       r^l, {l, 1, Infinity}]);
e = -Grad[v, {r, \[Theta], \[CurlyPhi]}, "Spherical"];
d = Simplify[
   Div[e /. Sum -> Inactive[Sum], {r, \[Theta], \[CurlyPhi]}, 
    "Spherical"]];
d = Activate[d]


Not sure why so many answers, when this is what happens:
Simplify[1 - Cos[x]^2]

(*  Sin[x]^2  *)


Not sure why so many answers I guess because no one tried just the Simplify command :)

TrigFactor[1 - Cos[x]^2]


$\sin ^2(x)$


In 14.1 on Windows
Simplify[Simplify[1 - Cos[x]^2 // TrigToExp] // ComplexExpand]


Sin[x]^2


The downvoter: What is incorrect in my answer? It is unfair to down vote without  any explaining comment.
